# C# Project Google map

Tags: c#, web-services, google-maps

For my studying and university I have a project where I need to make an application using C# WPF. This application must allow me to select a path between two adresses and show the path on the map like google map.

How can I implement the google webservice API ? I am a bit lost with it and I don't understand how I can make my application and fit in the google map itself.

With this i must be able to calculate the distance as well.

This is what i have done with the webBrowser but it displays the whole website of google maps:

I know that the WebBrowser control can display the google maps but it doesnt actually work
This is my code actually

```
    private void btnCharger_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Use static or WebControl we don't know yet.
        //This is the case we use webControl
        string street = "";
        string city = "";
        string zipcode = "";
        StringBuilder adresseQuery = new StringBuilder();
        adresseQuery.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");

        street = tbStreet.Text.Replace(" ", "+");
        adresseQuery.Append(street + ",+");
        city = tbCity.Text;
        adresseQuery.Append(city + ",+");
        zipcode = tbZipCode.Text;

        webBrowser1.Navigate(adresseQuery.ToString());*/


    }
```

So in this code i have created the adresse and sent it to the webbrowser through google maps. But is shows the whole google map page with the left bar and everything. I would like to only display the map ! How can i only display the map and not the bars present on the https://maps.google.com/

I have already checked this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238551/WPF-Map-App-WPF-meets-Google-Geocoding-Static-Maps) and am currently working on it but this is static.

Answer (score 0):

For the part of routing/getting the directions (and for some of others functions you need as well), you can use a .NET wrapper around Google Maps API:

1. [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi)
2. [google-maps](https://github.com/maximn/google-maps)

[gmaps-api-net](https://github.com/ericnewton76/gmaps-api-net) is outdated (at this time of answering) - the last update for the Directions API was made in 2016.

Usage example for [GoogleApi](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi):

```
using GoogleApi.Entities.Common;
using GoogleApi.Entities.Maps.Directions.Request;
using GoogleApi.Entities.Maps.Directions.Response;

public void GetRoute()
{
    DirectionsRequest request = new DirectionsRequest();    

    request.Key = "AIzaSyAJgBs8LYok3rt15rZUg4aUxYIAYyFzNcw";

    request.Origin = new Location("Brasov");
    request.Destination = new Location("Merghindeal");

    var response = GoogleApi.GoogleMaps.Directions.Query(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Routes.First().Legs.First().DurationInTraffic);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Routes.First().Legs.First().Distance);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Routes.First().Legs.First().Steps);
}
```